# Get inner html out of an HTML template used with PHP

Tags: php, html

So I have a PHP code similar to this

```
<?php
    //some code here
?>
<form>
    <input />
</form>
```

And according to this example, I want to get the input's content  to use further in PHP and/or insert in the desired input some variables from my PHP code, how can I perform this?

Comment: Use ajax to get compute data in php from front end data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post the data to php from a HTML form

```
<?php 
// data is available in php POST array
var_dump($_POST);

// create a var to hold the post data
$sNameOfPostVar = "";

// if posted, set the var to the value of the posted content
if(isset($_POST['NameOfPostVar'])){
    $sNameOfPostVar = $_POST['NameOfPostVar'];
}
?>

<!-- current action is blank to send to same page as php script -->
<form method='post' action=''>
    <input name='NameOfPostVar' value='<?php echo $sNameOfPostVar;?>' />
</form>
```